# Avoiding type <class 'method'> in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a code that I am trying to run and it should be fairly simple, it is just math. But whenever I try to do the math with the Pandas Dataframes I'm using, I'm getting an error. I know that in the dataframe, it is the column labeled 'first' which is giving me some issues. I have gone through and checked all the others. I have also tried a few things to convert it to a column with floating point values, so I can do the math with it. But I am getting errors every time. I am attaching the code along with comments of what I have tried and what errors I have been getting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am very stuck on this. Thank you!

```
# Set constants
pi = 3.14159265359
e = 2.71828
h = 6.62607004*(10**-34) # J*s
c = 299792458 # m / s
kb = 1.380649*(10**-23) # J/K
temp3 = 3000 # K
temp10 = 10000 # K
constant = (2*pi*h*(c**2))

bb_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'wl_nm' : range(200, 1101 ,1)}) # Gets wavelength ranges I will want plotted
#bb_df.wl
bb_df['wl_m'] = (bb_df.wl_nm * (10**-9)) # Gets wavelength in meters (this one does work doing math with)
bb_df['first'] = constant/((bb_df.wl_m)**5) # This one does not work doing math with; says it's a method, not number, and cannot figure out how to change it
#bb_df['first'] = bb_df['first'].astype(float) # Tried this, but get error: TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'method'>
#float(bb_df['first']) # Tried this, but get error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
bb_df['exponent'] = (h*c)/((bb_df.wl_m)*kb*temp3)
bb_df['denominator'] = e ** (bb_df.exponent) - 1
bb_df['second'] = 1 / bb_df.denominator
bb_df['second'] = bb_df.second + 1
bb_df['final'] = (bb_df.first) * (bb_df.second) # ERROR (because of bb_df.first)


#bb_df['test'] = float(bb_df.first) - float(bb_df.second)

#bb_df['intensity'] = (((2*pi*h*(c**2))/((bb_df.wl_m**5))(1/(e**((h*c)/((bb_df.wl_m)*kb*temp3))-1)))) # Also just tried typing out entire equation here, but this also gives an error

print(bb_df)
```

When I comment out all the lines that are not working, this is the dataframe I get. It is the 'first' column that says it is a method, and I have been trouble converting it to a floating point value to do math with. I thought perhaps it was because the number is so small, but then I should also not have had the issue when I just tried to do the entire equation all at once (in the 'intensity' column attempt, which also did not work):

```
     wl_nm          wl_m         first   exponent   denominator    second
0      200  2.000000e-07  1.169304e+18  23.979614  2.595417e+10  1.000000
1      201  2.010000e-07  1.140505e+18  23.860313  2.303537e+10  1.000000
2      202  2.020000e-07  1.112552e+18  23.742192  2.046898e+10  1.000000
3      203  2.030000e-07  1.085418e+18  23.625236  1.820969e+10  1.000000
4      204  2.040000e-07  1.059074e+18  23.509426  1.621836e+10  1.000000
..     ...           ...           ...        ...           ...       ...
896   1096  1.096000e-06  2.366053e+14   4.375842  7.850652e+01  1.012738
897   1097  1.097000e-06  2.355289e+14   4.371853  7.819001e+01  1.012789
898   1098  1.098000e-06  2.344583e+14   4.367871  7.787533e+01  1.012841
899   1099  1.099000e-06  2.333935e+14   4.363897  7.756247e+01  1.012893
900   1100  1.100000e-06  2.323346e+14   4.359930  7.725142e+01  1.012945

[901 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: "I am attaching the code along with comments of what I have tried and what errors I have been getting." I can't see your errors. You should show a separate example for each attempt, and for each show the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) error message, in a separate formatted code block. You should also explain why you don't think the column's data type is already `float`. (Note that if it failed to calculate the values in the first place, you can't fix that by converting the type *afterward*).

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to take a more organized approach to diagnosing the problem. You should also try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by keeping only the processing that is relevant to causing the problem.

Comment: "It is the 'first' column that says it is a method, and I have been trouble converting it to a floating point value to do math with." I don't understand this explanation at all. What is "it", and how does it say it "is a method"? The result that you show, shows a `first` column that correctly contains floating-point values with which you can do math without a problem.

Comment: I copied your code and just changed every reference of `bb_df.columnname` to `bb_df['columnname']` , I don't know what's stopping you but it's working without errors...

Comment: You are right, it does work with that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access):

> The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. `s.min` is not allowed, but `s['min']` is possible.

You cannot use `bb_df.first` to mean the same thing as `bb_df['first']`, because there is already [a `.first` method of the `DataFrame` class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html). That's why the error message tells you that `bb_df.first` is a method - because it is, one that is pre-defined by Pandas. The `first` column of your `DataFrame` contains floating-point values the entire time, and no attempt to convert the already-floating-point values into floating-point is relevant because the problem is not with the column. The problem is that the code `bb_df.first` *does not access the column*.

Just use indexing consistently (`bb_df['first']`). The other way is a not-really-convenience that results in this problem sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing `bb_df.columnname`, change it to `bb_df['columnname']`. It fixes the issue!